# SQL Server sending mail using xp_smtp_sendmail procedure

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have configured my SQL Server 2008 R2 with the following commands and steps.

1. for the mail configuration, I have downloaded `XPSMTP70.ZIP` and copy `xpsmtp70.dll` into  `C:Program Files\MSSQL\80\Tool\binn`
2. Then I executed `exec sp_addextendedproc 'xp_smtp_sendmail', 'xpsmtp70.dll'` in the `Master` database. I also executed `grant execute on xp_smtp_sendmail to public` in the `master` database.

But when I run this code to send mail

```
EXEC master.dbo.xp_smtp_sendmail 
        @TO = 'vipin.v@fingent.com', 
        @from = 'vipinv65@gmail.com', 
        @message = 'fgsdjfgsd sdfsdgfsdg sdjfdsjgh', 
        @subject = 'foo was fired.', 
        @server = 'smtp.gmail.com' `
```

I get an error message

> Could not load the DLL xpsmtp70.dll, or one of the DLLs it
>   references. Reason: 126 (The specified module could not be found.).

Please help ....

Comment: Your server is in mess. xpsmtp70.dll is related to SQL Server 7.0. "C\\:Program Files\MSSQL\80\Tool\binn" path is related to SQL Server 2000 and you are trying to set up SQL Server 2008 R2 Database mail. Follow @marc_s advice and set up Database mail from scratch.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, in SQL Server 2005 and up, you are better off **not** using the old mail stuff based on "SQL Mail" and extended procedures.

Instead, use the built-in Database Mail - see [SQL Server 2008 - Configure Database Mail](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/23/sql-server-2008-configure-database-mail-send-email-from-sql-database/) for a step-by-step procedure on how to set it up and use it